# & symbol in title breaking variable

Tags: php

Currently I am trying to make it so that if my title contains `&` in the title it will pass through the url below.

```
dl.php?&u='.$mp3.'&n='.$auth2.'
```

Currently I have the following code

```
$auth = urlencode($title2); 
$auth2 = urldecode($auth);
$title2 = 'Artist - Song Name (Feat. Another Artist & Last Artist)';
```

You can see below that the `$title2` portion contains an `&` symbol, if this passes through our URL the download will look like this `Artist - Song Name (Feat. Another Artist)` leaving out the last artist in the MP3's name.

Any help is gratefully appreciated.

Comment: did you put the `$title2` variable to the top of the two lines? What happens then?

Comment: `rawurlencode($title2)`

Comment: @bishop doesn't seem to work.. I tried that previously also, not sure what I am doing wrong as all the comments thus far point to basically what's already being done.

Comment: [Works for me](https://3v4l.org/O1mCp). You have another issue going on, possibly a double encoding. As a work around, you might try `rawurlencode(htmlentities($title2))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix the URL first so you can parse it correctly later on. Use `http_build_query`: http://php.net/http_build_query, it will urlencode things correctly for you

```
'dl.php?' . http_build_query(array('u' => $mp3, 'n' => $auth2));
```

Comment: Seems quite handy, rather upset I had not learned about it sooner.

Answer (score 1):

If you urlencode `$title2`, you won't have this problem.

```
$title2 = urlencode('Artist - Song Name (Feat. Another Artist & Last Artist)');
```

Alternatively, you can use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query) to construct your querystring:

```
$params = [
    'u' => $mp3,
    'n' => $title2
];
$queryString = http_build_query($params);
$url = 'dl.php?' . $queryString;
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can do this :

**`dl.php?&u='.urlencode($mp3).'&n='.urlencode($title2).'`**

This will encode your title and URL will be like this :

**`dl.php?&u=MP3contentwillcomehere&n=Artist+-+Song+Name+%28Feat.+Another+Artist+%26+Last+Artist%29`**

OR you can use **http_build_query**:

```
$mp3 = "MP3 content";
$name = "Artist - Song Name (Feat. Another Artist & Last Artist)";
$build = http_build_query(array('u' => $mp3, 'n' => $name));
```

which will output : 
**u=MP3+content&n=Artist+-+Song+Name+%28Feat.+Another+Artist+%26+Last+Artist%29**

```
"dl.php?".$build;
```